# 3D shapes similarity

Tags: python, 3d, similarity

I'm looking for a python module which would allow me to compare two 3D shapes and assess their similarity. I tried OpenCV's createHausdorffDistanceExtractor() class, but it seems not to work anymore. any other modules I could try?

the geometries I want to compare are NURBS surfaces, but I can generate projections, images, etc., if necessary.